# GitVersion with Agent and Incrementing

Tags: c#, asp.net, tfs-2015, gitversion

I am looking for a way to use semantic versioning to have $(Major).$(Minor).$(Fix) on the file version of my project dll as well as on TFS2015. I succeeded to have it but now I face other troubles (see below)

I use the following lines in the .csproj which works very well to apply the buildnumber created by gitversion task:

```
<Version Condition=" '$(BUILD_BUILDNUMBER)' == '' ">1.0.1-local</Version>
<Version Condition=" '$(BUILD_BUILDNUMBER)' != '' ">$(BUILD_BUILDNUMBER)</Version>
```

The problem is that I am using an agent so it makes it a bit more difficult it seems that config is in .git\gitversion_cache*.yml.

I have read ton of documentation and currently I am able to use this .yml file but it looks like it is generated on the agent and then it is not replaced with default values 0.0.1+26.

So :
1) should I commit the yml config file or have it in a specific folder in the agent ? If on the agent how to tell tfs2015 where it is located ? The agent build directory is sometimes cleaned...
2) how you can auto-increment the $(Fix) variable?
3) how to have a command line to increase major and minor when there is a change? I could not find any information...

Regards,

Comment: The GitVersion documentation answers a lot of your questions. Did you read that before asking?

Comment: yes of course : https://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build-server-support/build-server/tfs-build-vnext/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a solution that was to always add:

```
 +semver: fix
```

to the commit message. I wish it could be setupped somewhere else but for now I will use this solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could add task [Update Assembly Info](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bool.update-assembly-info) in your TFS build definition, to update assembly info of one or multiple files or projects during build.

Or add powershell task to set assembly versions. Check the blog below:

https://writeabout.net/2015/11/01/set-assembly-and-app-version-to-a-matching-build-name-in-tfs-2015-or-vso-build-vnext/

Comment: It is already done and not answering my questions, but thank you anyways.

Comment: Do you use `Update Assembly Info` task or the powershell script?

Comment: Update Assembly Info, the checkbox from gitversion I mean

Comment: I am okay to use the 'Update Assembly Info' extension but I dont see where I could increment it for major minor etc. ?